# Flask WTForms submit button not working at all

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms, web-development-server

I'm trying to make a registeration page using WTForms but I'm having difficulties getting the submit button to work. When I fill all the page's fields and click the 'Submit' button nothing happens whatsoever, I checked the database to see if the form instance was even created and it wasn't, I also don't get redirected to the desired URL after submitting.

I'm currently following a Flask tutorial for Python on YT by JimShapedCoding [Link to video](https://youtu.be/E1An29BZWBk)

Here's my code:

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy    #tables using classes

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///market.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'b61198e1258118d75478e8e4'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


from market import routes
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField


class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(label='Enter your username:')
    email_address = StringField(label='Email:')
    pw1 = PasswordField(label='Password:')
    pw2 = PasswordField(label='Confirm Password:')
    submit = SubmitField(label='Create Account')
```

models.py

```
from market import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(length=18), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email_address = db.Column(db.String(length=40), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(length=60), nullable=False)
    budget = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, default=1000)
    items = db.relationship('Item', backref='owned_user', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item: {self.name}"
```

routes.py

```
from market import app
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from market.models import Item, User
from market.forms import RegisterForm
from market import db

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register_page():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user_to_create = User(username=form.username.data,
                              email_address=form.email_address.data,
                              password_hash=form.pw1.data)    
        db.session.add(user_to_create)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('market_page'))

    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

run.py

```
from market import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

templates folder:

register.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Register 
{% endblock %}   
{% block content %}
<body  class='text-center'>
    <div class="container"
        <form method="POST" action="/market" class="form-register" style="color:white">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <img class="mb-4" src="" alt="">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">
                Please Create your Account
            </h1>
            <br>
            
            {{ form.username.label() }}
            {{ form.username(class="form-control", placeholder="Username") }}
            
            {{ form.email_address.label() }}
            {{ form.email_address(class="form-control", placeholder="Email Address") }}
            
            {{ form.pw1.label() }}
            {{ form.pw1(class="form-control", placeholder="Password") }}
            
            {{ form.pw2.label() }}
            {{ form.pw2(class="form-control", placeholder="Confirm Password") }}
            
            <br>
            
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary") }} 
        </form>
    </div>
</body>  
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <title>
        {% block title %}

        {% endblock%}
      </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Flask Market</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home_page') }}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('market_page') }}">Market</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('register_page') }}">Register</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock %}
   </body>
   <style>
      body {
      background-color: #212121;
      color: white
      }
   </style>
</html>
```

[Photo of my project layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5GUa.png)

[How the registeration page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgxkt.png)

After revising my code multiple times & making sure it's like what was in the video, I still couldn't manage to fix my issue or even impact it.

What I tried:

I tried using `app.app_context().push()`

before the `db.session.add(user_to_create)`
line in routes.py

I made sure all the variable names matched

I tried running it using *$env:FLASK_APP = '**init**.py'* followed by *flask run*

This is how my terminal looks like whenever the page is refreshed:

**127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2023 23:09:02] "GET /register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2023 23:09:11] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -**

If anyone may offer some help that'll be wonderful as I have been trying to debug this issue for around 3 days now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take checkout at [tour], [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why is the action attribute of the form pointing to `/market` and not `/register`?

Comment: @Detlef I changed it to /register and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains a typo in the `register.html` file. The `div` element that encloses the form is missing the trailing `>` before the form element begins.

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- Your form here. -->
</div>
```